# Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK ad Mediator in XAML UWP apps

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

On my primary development machine I created an app that can be deployed but lacked advertising. That machine broke and was sent in for repair, thankfully after I committed the working application to source control. I brought up a spare machine, checked out my project making many improvements including successfully displaying adds in the windows 10 UWP application. After repairs were completed on my primary development machine I updated templates, and SDKs that had changed during the repair, ?I believe I got them all?. I checked out the project and after a successful build attempted to deploy and debug.

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: Decisive.Uwp.T10, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>Updating the layout...
2>Copying files: Total 1 mb to layout...
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
2>Framework: Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml/x86, app package version 10.0.1510.0 is not currently installed.
2>Installing missing frameworks...
2>Error : DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml\10.0\.\AppX\x86\Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml.x86.10.0.appx" failed to install. 
2>error 0x80070005: Opening the package from location Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml.x86.10.0.appx failed.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I removed the **Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml, Version=10.0** leaving the **Microsoft.AdMediator.Universal, Version=1.0** The app will now deploy and run but doesn't appear to display adds. I noticed the following warning;

(I don't know how to format the following with wrap so it doesn't need to be scrolled many page widths. I've left it as a paragraph.)

The SDK "Microsoft.AdMediator.Universal, Version=1.0" depends on the following SDK(s) "Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml, Version=10.0", which have not been added to the project or were not found. Please ensure that you add these dependencies to your project or you may experience runtime issues. You can add dependencies to your project through the Reference Manager.

The versions of these two libraries match between the two machines used to created this app.

I'm at a loss attempting to resolve this error **Error : DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml\10.0.\AppX\x86\Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml.x86.10.0.appx" failed to install.**

**Additional Information 10/21/2015 2008 MST**
FWIW With both references intact, in a state where it won't deploy to my windows 10 notebook locally or in the emulator, I deployed to a windows phone mobile emulator. No errors, app runs. Doesn't appear to be displaying ads though.

On the spare machine where the app will deploy to windows 10 locally and display ads, ads are displayed in both the win10 emulator and the mobile emulator.

**Additional Information 10/22/2015 0930 MST**
The comments on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/09/16/wintools-1-1-typescript-1-6-rtm-and-tools-for-apache-cordova-updates.aspx) post regarding *WinTools 1.1, TypeScript 1.6 RTM, and Tools for Apache Cordova Updates* may shed some light on the problem. They detail a problem that some developers have experienced installing the win tools 1.1 update that apparently the AdMediator relies on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some great hindsight and you can see what assumptions made out of me.

I got in touch with a PM at Microsoft who stated;

> Yes, we are aware of the issue that you are talking about. But that
>   issue might be a red herring in this context – it is all about just
>   false notifications showing up when you do the upgrade. That should
>   not have really caused the issue with the AdControl (if you truly had
>   the issue with a bogus install of the tools, you could not even create
>   or build a UWP app of any kind).

Eventually I tried running Visual Studio as Administrator. I was able to deploy the app. Afterwards I exited Visual Studio then restarted with normal privileges. I am now able to deploy the app without running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: Holly yikes! Misspelling 'now' as 'not' changed my answer 180! Corrected not to now.